# Having both mouse events and bar transitions

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, mouseevent

My intention is to create a graph that has a bar height transition every time it is drawn/ redrawn, and then once the bar is displayed, there can be mouse events (mouseenter, mouseleave, and mousemove) that will display a tooltip with info of the bar you're hovering over.

I have made it so that the mouse events are working, but where do I add the transition? If I add the transition above the '.attr("height")' the transition works, but then the X and Y axis aren't drawn and I get the error "unknown type: mouseenter." If I place the transition outside of the bar selection, and I do 'bar.transition()...,' the transition doesn't display but the X and Y axis are drawn and mouse event works.

Am I missing something? My understanding of how D3/ javascript nested function work is shoddy since we never discussed them in class, so I'm most likely overlooking a basic principle of how D3 properties are applied, etc.

EDIT: Looking at it, should I be declaring the transition above the

```
.attr('height', function (d)...
```

And I should move the click events to the bottom so that it's

```
bar.on('mouseenter', function (d)...
```

Current code:

```
function drawHistogram(type = 3, title = 'Total Count by Name - Alphabetically') {
    var url = "histogramData.tsv";

    var margin = 100;
    var width = 1000 - (margin * 2);
    var height = 500 - (margin * 2);

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .padding(0.1); // space between bars

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select('#graphBox').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin + margin)
        .attr('height', height + margin + margin)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform',
            'translate(' + margin + ',' + margin + ')');

    // add graph title and x/y labels
    svg.append('text')
        ...

    var gradient = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 50])
        .range(['rgb(253,203,90)', 'rgb(253,56,170)']);

    d3.tsv(url, function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        // sort data based on type
        if (type == 0) { // name Z to A
            data.sort(function (a, b) {
                return d3.descending(a.name, b.name)
            });
        } else if (type == 1) { // count lowest to highest
            data.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.count - b.count;
            });
        } else if (type == 2) { // count highest to lowest
            data.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b.count - a.count;
            });
        } // name A to Z

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.count = +d.count;
        });

        x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));

        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.count;
        })]);

        var bar = svg.selectAll('.bar')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')

            .attr('x', function (d) {
                return x(d.name);
            })

            .attr('y', function (d) {
                return y(d.count);
            })
            .attr('width', x.bandwidth())

            // This is the transition code, this transition will allow the bars to dropdown. 
            // If you uncomment this, the bar effect will work as intended, however, my axis
            // are no longer drawn and the mouse events do not work. But the transition works.

            /*
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .delay(function (d, i) {
                return i * 20;
            })
            */

            .attr('height', function (d) {
                return height - y(d.count);
            })

            // give bars horizontal gradient fill
            .style('fill', function (d, i) {
                return gradient(i);
            })

            .on('mouseenter', function (d) {
                bar = d3.select(this)
                    .attr('opacity', 0.5)

                tooltip.style('display', null)
                    .raise()
            })

            .on('mouseleave', function (d) {
                d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1)
                tooltip.style('display', 'none')
            })

            .on('mousemove', function (d) {
                var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0] + 5;
                var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 40;
                tooltip.attr('transform', 'translate(' + xPos + ',' + yPos + ')');
                tooltip.select('#name').text('Name: ' + d.name);
                tooltip.select('#count').text('Count: ' + d.count);
            });

        // I tried to add the transition outside of the bar's creation.
        // and call it here while adding the transition.
        // The transition here does not do anything but the axis are drawn
        // and mouse events work properly. 

        /*
        bar.transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .delay(function (d, i) {
                return i * 20;
            })
        */

        // add x and y axis legends
        svg.append('g')
            ...

        // add a clickable line over the x axis to sort chart alphabetically 
        svg.append('line')
            ...

        // add a clickable line over the y axis to sort chart by value
        svg.append('line')
            ....

    });

    // tooltip item
    var tooltip = svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'tooltip')
        .style('display', 'none');

    tooltip.append('rect')
        .attr('width', 80)
        .attr('height', 35)
        .attr('fill', 'white')
        .style('opacity', 1);

    tooltip.append('text')
        .attr('id', 'name')
        .attr('x', '0.5em')
        .attr('dy', '1.3em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'left')

    tooltip.append('text')
        .attr('id', 'count')
        .attr('x', '0.5em')
        .attr('dy', '2.3em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'left')
}
```

Comment: You need to use the `join` function or follow the update-enter-exit pattern for the bars. You can likely search for either option with plenty of answers here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't subscribe to mouse events in transitions, so you should have the .on before the .transition.

Try something like this:

```
    var bar = svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
            return x(d.name);
        })
        .attr('y', function (d) {
            return y(d.count);
        })
        .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
        .on('mouseenter', function (d) {
            bar = d3.select(this)
                .attr('opacity', 0.5)

            tooltip.style('display', null)
                .raise()
        })
        .on('mouseleave', function (d) {
            d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1)
            tooltip.style('display', 'none')
        })
        .on('mousemove', function (d) {
            var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0] + 5;
            var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 40;
            tooltip.attr('transform', 'translate(' + xPos + ',' + yPos + ')');
            tooltip.select('#name').text('Name: ' + d.name);
            tooltip.select('#count').text('Count: ' + d.count);
        })
        .transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .delay(function (d, i) {
            return i * 20;
        })
        .attr('height', function (d) {
            return height - y(d.count);
        })
        // give bars horizontal gradient fill
        .style('fill', function (d, i) {
            return gradient(i);
        });
```

Comment: Oh, that's why. Thanks a lot! Just for clarification though, what do you mean exactly by "events in transition"? My first assumption for this not working was because you can't mouse over something that's not "there" since it's doing a transition. However, after editing the code to match your code, it works and the tool tip displays even though the transition animation is still in progress.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough, calling .on after .transition is possible, but you would be able to subscribe to different events, like 'start' and 'end', 'mouseover', for instance, doesn't exist for a transition event, that's the error that you were receiving. So you can subscribe to mouse over events in selections, just like you did when you updated your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small misunderstanding in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58107635/5768908): you **can** subscribe to mouse events in the transitions, that's not a problem.

The issue is just a matter of method names. For whatever reason, D3 creator decided to give two different methods the same name. Therefore, the `on()` here:

```
selection.on
```

Is **not** the same method of the `on()` here:

```
transition.on
```

They are different methods, with the same name. That being said, `transition.on` is not used for mouse events (that would be `selection.on` instead), and it accepts only 4 typenames:

- `"start"`
- `"end"`
- `"interrupt"`
- `"cancel"`

And here you have a demo showing that you can subscribe to mouse events during a transition, provided that you use `selection.on` (in this example, `d3.select(this).on...`). Hover over the black rectangle, there is no mouse event listener. After the transition starts, the mouse event listener works:

```js
const rect = d3.select("rect");
rect.transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(5000)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .on("start", function() {
    d3.select(this).on("mousemove", function() {
      console.log("The mouse is over!");
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="150"></rect>
</svg>
```

Or you can also use the less known [`transition.selection()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_selection), which returns the selection corresponding to the transition. The difference from the snippet above is that here the listener is immediately attached:

```js
const rect = d3.select("rect");
rect.transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(5000)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .selection()
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    console.log("The mouse is over!");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect width="100" height="150"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Didn't know that '.on' is the same name for two different functions. That would explain the error a bit more and why it occurred.

Comment: Wow! I did't know that either, I thought they were the same method accepting different parameters, sorry for the troubles. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks Gerardo for pointing this out. Sorry @dwang040 for the mistake.

Comment: @GuillermoGarcia No, your answer must remain the accepted one, since you provided a **solution** (*"you should have the .on before the .transition"*). I'm just explaining what's happening here.

Comment: No worries. The code was able to help solve my issue, and the explanation helped explain why it was occurring. Appreciate both of your help!